# intellij idea doesn't show file status colors

Tags: intellij-idea

I have an intellij idea Java project under GIT. When I modify a file I don't see any [status change](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-status-highlights.html) in my package view.

[image: GIT integration is enabled.]

I expect to see an indication in the package view that a file was modified.

I Eclipse IDE I can see:

[image]

Comment: What do you see in the git/vcs menu (ALT+9)? Does IntelliJ IDEA treat your project as a git project?

Comment: Have you enabled [Git integration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-git-integration.html)?

Comment: GIT integration is enabled.